# How to make this code simpler, clearer and "more lispy"?

Tags: common-lisp

I want to parse the text line from the [Wavefront OBJ file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file). Currently I am interested in "V" and "F" types only.
My algorithm is as follows:

1. check if line is not nil (otherwise step 2 would fail)
2. drop comment after "#" and trim spaces
3. drop prefix "v " or "f "
4. split string to the list of elements where each element

   1. is split to the list if it is symbol like |34/76/23|
   2. is converted from the list: I take one element only, the first by default
   3. or coerced to the given type if it is atomic number already.

Here is the code:

```
(defun parse-line (line prefix &key (type 'single-float))
  (declare (optimize (debug 3)))
  (labels ((rfs (what)
             (read-from-string (concatenate 'string "(" what ")")))
           (unpack (str &key (char #\/) (n 0))
             (let ((*readtable* (copy-readtable))) 
               (when char ;; we make the given char a delimiter (space)
                 (set-syntax-from-char char #\Space))
               (typecase str
                 ;; string -> list of possibly symbols.
                 ;; all elements are preserved by (map). nil's are dropped
                 (string (delete-if #'null
                                    (map 'list
                                         #'unpack
                                         (rfs str))))
                 ;; symbol -> list of values
                 (symbol (unpack (rfs (symbol-name str))))
                 ;; list -> value (only the requested one)
                 (list (unpack (nth n str)))
                 ;; value -> just coerce to type
                 (number (coerce str type))))))
    (and line
         (setf line (string-trim '(#\Space #\Tab)
                                 (subseq line 0 (position #\# line))))
         (< (length prefix) (length line))
         (string= line prefix :end1 (length prefix) :end2 (length prefix))
         (setf line (subseq line (length prefix)))
         (let ((value (unpack line :char nil))) 
           (case (length value)
               (3 value)
               (4 (values (subseq value 0 3) ;; split quad 0-1-2-3 on tri 0-1-2 + tri 0-2-3
                          (list (nth 0 value)
                                (nth 2 value)
                                (nth 3 value)))))))))
```

Step four (label "unpack") is kind of recursive. It is one function and can call itself three times.

Anyway, this solution seems to be clunky.

My question is: how should one solve this task with shorter and clearer code?

Comment: How to make the code more lispy? More parentheses, of course. Also, global search and replace 's' with 'th'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would approach this in a more structured manner.

You want to parse an obj file into some sort of data structure:

```
(defun parse-obj-file (filespec)
  ;; todo
  )
```

You need to think about how the data structure returned should look. For now, let us return a list of two lists, one of the vertices, one of the faces.  The parser will go through each line, determine whether it is either a vertex or a face, and then collect it into the appropriate list:

```
(defun parse-obj-file (filespec)
  (with-open-file (in-stream filespec
                             :direction :input)
    (loop for line = (read-line in-stream nil)
          while line
          when (cl-ppcre:scan "^v " line)
          collect (parse-vertex line) into vertices
          when (cl-ppcre:scan "^f " line)
          collect (parse-face line) into faces
          finally (return (list vertices faces)))))
```

I used the `cl-ppcre` library here, but you could also use `mismatch` or `search`.  You will then need to define `parse-vertex` and `parse-face`, for which `cl-ppcre:split` should come in quite handy.

It would perhaps also be useful to define classes for vertices and faces.

*Update:*  This is how I would approach vertices:

```
(defclass vertex ()
  ((x :accessor x :initarg :x)
   (y :accessor y :initarg :y)
   (z :accessor z :initarg :z)
   (w :accessor w :initarg :w)))

(defun parse-vertex (line)
  (destructuring-bind (label x y z &optional w)
      (cl-ppcre:split "\\s+" (remove-comment line))
    (declare (ignorable label))
    (make-instance 'vertex
                   :x (parse-number x)
                   :y (parse-number y)
                   :z (parse-number z)
                   :w (parse-number w))))
```

`Parse-number` is from the `parse-number` library.  It is better than using `read`.

*Update 2:* (Sorry for making this a run-on story; I have to interlace some work.) A face consists of a list of face-points.

```
(defclass face-point ()
  ((vertex-index :accessor vertex-index :initarg :vertex-index)
   (texture-coordinate :accessor texture-coordinate
                       :initarg :texture-coordinate)
   (normal :accessor normal :initarg :normal)))

(defun parse-face (line)
  (destructuring-bind (label &rest face-points)
      (cl-ppcre:split "\\s+" (remove-comment line))
    (declare (ignorable label))
    (mapcar #'parse-face-point face-points)))

(defun parse-face-point (string)
  (destructuring-bind (vertex-index &optional texture-coordinate normal)
      (cl-ppcre:split "/" string)
    (make-instance 'face-point
                   :vertex-index vertex-index
                   :texture-coordinate texture-coordinate
                   :normal normal)))
```

`Remove-comment` simply throws away everything after the first `#`:

```
(defun remove-comment (line)
  (subseq line 0 (position #\# line)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I cannot show here in comments my legacy code. So I just mention, that I started with (removecomment...) function, but then decided, that treating #\# as #\\) is easier.

Comment: @avp:  The Lisp reader should be used to read Lisp code.  Massaging your input to be `read`able is a rather convoluted approach.

Comment: But if it makes the code smaller and easier to understand? (And I assume the file format is correct, too.

Comment: @avp: No, it does not make it easier to understand.  You do several conversions of strings to symbols, strings to lists, symbols to strings, and finally perhaps strings to numbers, all while mucking around with the readtable, instead of simply splitting your input and parsing the parts.